# Cant display the fontawesome using binding properties .It only works directly on the XAML

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding, font-awesome

I want to bind some fontawesome icons into my XAML via view model.
I have it as following

Models

```
 public string Icon { get; set; }
```

ViewModel

```
new Models.Item {Icon="&#xf713;",},
```

XAML

```
<Label>
  <Span Text="{Binding Icon}"FontFamily="Materiales" FontSize="22"  />     
                </Label>
```

[image: I get it as text not the icon .]

[image]

What do I need to change or add?

Comment: Are you using the correct FontFamily

Comment: Yes , it renders the icon if I use it from XAML

Comment: I post my answer and I use the MVVM to bind the data. It works well on my side. Do you have checked the binding problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `C#` strings the escape character for the icon code is `\u`. If the icon code is `f000`, the string in `C#` becomes:

```
"\uf000"
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a demo about the `fontFamily` and used the steps below.

First, I import the `Lobster-Regular.ttf` file to the project

Second, I set the Build Action of file to `EmbeddedResource` then put the code below into the `AssemblyInfo.cs`

```
[assembly: ExportFont("Lobster-Regular.ttf", Alias = "Lobster")]
```

Third, I use the MVVM method to bind the data to the label like this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Name}"  FontFamily="Lobster-Regular"></Label>
```

Here is the view of the label:

[image]

Comment: Thank you , it was a combination of your input and the icon code